# page not bringing through the correct row from the table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I seem to be having problems with this line of code, it should be bring through the reference field in the address bar of the browser.

```
echo <a href="update.php?Reference=<? echo $rows['Reference']; ?>">update</a>
```

it should look like this in the address bar 
"localip/update.php?Reference=123456"

but instead is like this
"localip/update.php?Reference="

it doesn't seem to be bringing through the field into the address bar to display the information about that row in the table.

any help would be much appreciated (pretty new to all of this)

Cheers

UPDATE -

```
require_once('auth.php');

$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

 $Reference=$_POST['Reference'];
 $directly = $_POST['directly'];
 $behalfclient = $_POST['behalfclient'];
 $investigations = $_POST['investigations'];
 $injuries = $_POST['injuries'];
 $duties = $_POST['duties'];
 $Wherepain = $_POST['Wherepain'];
 $pain = $_POST['pain'];
 $aggravates = $_POST['aggravates'];
 $eases = $_POST['eases'];
 $Movement = $_POST['Movement'];
 $neural = $_POST['neural'];
 $UnderstandNPRS = $_POST['UnderstandNPRS'];
 $NPRSassessment = $_POST['NPRSassessment'];
 $yourhobbies = $_POST['yourhobbies'];
 $hobbiesaffected = $_POST['hobbiesaffected'];
 $social = $_POST['social'];
 $activities = $_POST['activities'];
 $lifestyle = $_POST['lifestyle'];
 $avoiddriving = $_POST['avoiddriving'];
 $grip = $_POST['grip'];
 $flashbacks = $_POST['flashbacks'];
 $braking = $_POST['braking'];
 $past = $_POST['past'];
 $psychologically = $_POST['psychologically'];
 $stomach = $_POST['stomach'];
 $dental = $_POST['dental'];
 $organs = $_POST['organs'];
 $genitals = $_POST['genitals'];
 $memory = $_POST['memory'];
 $scaring = $_POST['scaring'];
 $deformity = $_POST['deformity'];
 $eyes = $_POST['eyes'];
 $burns = $_POST['burns'];
 $head = $_POST['head'];
 $symptoms = $_POST['symptoms'];
 $otherchanges = $_POST['otherchanges'];
 $receivingtreatment = $_POST['receivingtreatment'];
 $surgery = $_POST['surgery'];
 $Impression = $_POST['Impression'];
 $management = $_POST['management'];
 $ifyes = $_POST['ifyes'];
 $Rehabilitation = $_POST['Rehabilitation'];
 $Number = $_POST['Number'];
 $Psychological = $_POST['Psychological'];
 $diagnostic = $_POST['diagnostic'];
 $notrequiretreatment = $_POST['notrequiretreatment'];
 $house = $_POST['house'];
 $recommendations = $_POST['recommendations'];
 $Prognosis = $_POST['Prognosis'];
 $CV = $_POST['CV'];
 $cervical = $_POST['cervical'];
 $heat = $_POST['heat'];
 $ice = $_POST['ice'];
 $lumbar = $_POST['lumbar'];
 $medication = $_POST['medication'];
 $posture = $_POST['posture'];
 $sport = $_POST['sport'];
 $given = $_POST['given'];
 $sceneaccident = $_POST['sceneaccident'];

 $sql="UPDATE Triage SET sceneaccident='$sceneaccident', notrequiretreatment='$notrequiretreatment', house='$house', recommendations='$recommendations', Prognosis='$Prognosis', CV='$CV', cervical='$cervical', heat='$heat', ice='$ice', lumbar='$lumbar', medication='$medication', posture='$posture', sport='$sport', given='$given' ,organs='$organs', deformity='$deformity', otherchanges='$otherchanges', receivingtreatment='$receivingtreatment', surgery='$surgery', Impression='$Impression', management='$management', ifyes='$ifyes', Rehabilitation='$Rehabilitation', Number='$Number', Psychological='$Psychological', diagnostic='$diagnostic', eyes='$eyes', burns='$burns', head='$head', symptoms='$symptoms', memory='$memory', scaring='$scaring', genitals='$genitals', dental='$dental', stomach='$stomach', directly='$directly', behalfclient='$behalfclient', investigations='$investigations', injuries='$injuries', duties='$duties', Wherepain='$Wherepain', pain='$pain', aggravates='$aggravates', eases='$eases', Movement='$Movement', neural='$neural', UnderstandNPRS='$UnderstandNPRS', NPRSassessment='$NPRSassessment', yourhobbies='$yourhobbies', hobbiesaffected='$hobbiesaffected', social='$social', activities='$activities', lifestyle='$lifestyle', avoiddriving='$avoiddriving', grip='$grip', flashbacks='$flashbacks', braking='$braking', past='$past', psychologically='$psychologically' WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);


if (!$_POST['sceneaccident'] || !$_POST['notrequiretreatment'] || !$_POST['house'] || !$_POST['recommendations'] || !$_POST['Prognosis'] || !$_POST['CV'] || !$_POST['cervical'] || !$_POST['heat'] || !$_POST['ice'] || !$_POST['lumbar'] || !$_POST['medication'] || !$_POST['posture'] || !$_POST['sport'] || !$_POST['given'] || !$_POST['organs'] || !$_POST['deformity'] || !$_POST['otherchanges'] || !$_POST['receivingtreatment'] || !$_POST['surgery'] || !$_POST['Impression'] || !$_POST['management'] || !$_POST['ifyes'] || !$_POST['Rehabilitation'] || !$_POST['Number'] || !$_POST['Psychological'] || !$_POST['diagnostic'] || !$_POST['eyes'] || !$_POST['burns'] || !$_POST['head'] || !$_POST['symptoms'] || !$_POST['memory'] || !$_POST['scaring'] || !$_POST['genitals'] || !$_POST['dental'] || !$_POST['stomach'] || !$_POST['directly'] || !$_POST['behalfclient'] || !$_POST['investigations'] || !$_POST['injuries'] || !$_POST['duties'] || !$_POST['Wherepain'] || !$_POST['pain'] || !$_POST['aggravates'] || !$_POST['eases'] || !$_POST['Movement'] || !$_POST['neural'] || !$_POST['UnderstandNPRS'] || !$_POST['NPRSassessment'] || !$_POST['yourhobbies'] || !$_POST['hobbiesaffected'] || !$_POST['social'] || !$_POST['activities'] || !$_POST['lifestyle'] || !$_POST['avoiddriving'] || !$_POST['grip'] || !$_POST['flashbacks'] || !$_POST['braking'] || !$_POST['past'] || !$_POST['psychologically'] )

{
 echo ('You did not complete all of the required fields');
 echo "<BR>";
 echo '<a href="update.php?Reference='. $rows['Reference'].' ">update</a>'; 
 }
 else {
 echo "Successful";
 echo "<BR>";
 echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
 } 

 ?>
```

UPDATE 2

```
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

 $Reference=$_REQUEST['Reference'];
 $directly = $_REQUEST['directly'];
 $behalfclient = $_REQUEST['behalfclient'];
 $investigations = $_REQUEST['investigations'];
 $injuries = $_REQUEST['injuries'];
 $duties = $_REQUEST['duties'];
 $Wherepain = $_REQUEST['Wherepain'];
 $pain = $_REQUEST['pain'];
 $aggravates = $_REQUEST['aggravates'];
 $eases = $_REQUEST['eases'];
 $Movement = $_REQUEST['Movement'];
 $neural = $_REQUEST['neural'];
 $UnderstandNPRS = $_REQUEST['UnderstandNPRS'];
 $NPRSassessment = $_REQUEST['NPRSassessment'];
 $yourhobbies = $_REQUEST['yourhobbies'];
 $hobbiesaffected = $_REQUEST['hobbiesaffected'];
 $social = $_REQUEST['social'];
 $activities = $_REQUEST['activities'];
 $lifestyle = $_REQUEST['lifestyle'];
 $avoiddriving = $_REQUEST['avoiddriving'];
 $grip = $_REQUEST['grip'];
 $flashbacks = $_REQUEST['flashbacks'];
 $braking = $_REQUEST['braking'];
 $past = $_REQUEST['past'];
 $psychologically = $_REQUEST['psychologically'];
 $stomach = $_REQUEST['stomach'];
 $dental = $_REQUEST['dental'];
 $organs = $_REQUEST['organs'];
 $genitals = $_REQUEST['genitals'];
 $memory = $_REQUEST['memory'];
 $scaring = $_REQUEST['scaring'];
 $deformity = $_REQUEST['deformity'];
 $eyes = $_REQUEST['eyes'];
 $burns = $_REQUEST['burns'];
 $head = $_REQUEST['head'];
 $symptoms = $_REQUEST['symptoms'];
 $otherchanges = $_REQUEST['otherchanges'];
 $receivingtreatment = $_REQUEST['receivingtreatment'];
 $surgery = $_REQUEST['surgery'];
 $Impression = $_REQUEST['Impression'];
 $management = $_REQUEST['management'];
 $ifyes = $_REQUEST['ifyes'];
 $Rehabilitation = $_REQUEST['Rehabilitation'];
 $Number = $_REQUEST['Number'];
 $Psychological = $_REQUEST['Psychological'];
 $diagnostic = $_REQUEST['diagnostic'];
 $notrequiretreatment = $_REQUEST['notrequiretreatment'];
 $house = $_REQUEST['house'];
 $recommendations = $_REQUEST['recommendations'];
 $Prognosis = $_REQUEST['Prognosis'];
 $CV = $_REQUEST['CV'];
 $cervical = $_REQUEST['cervical'];
 $heat = $_REQUEST['heat'];
 $ice = $_REQUEST['ice'];
 $lumbar = $_REQUEST['lumbar'];
 $medication = $_REQUEST['medication'];
 $posture = $_REQUEST['posture'];
 $sport = $_REQUEST['sport'];
 $given = $_REQUEST['given'];
 $sceneaccident = $_REQUEST['sceneaccident'];

 $sql="UPDATE Triage SET sceneaccident='$sceneaccident', notrequiretreatment='$notrequiretreatment', house='$house', recommendations='$recommendations', Prognosis='$Prognosis', CV='$CV', cervical='$cervical', heat='$heat', ice='$ice', lumbar='$lumbar', medication='$medication', posture='$posture', sport='$sport', given='$given' ,organs='$organs', deformity='$deformity', otherchanges='$otherchanges', receivingtreatment='$receivingtreatment', surgery='$surgery', Impression='$Impression', management='$management', ifyes='$ifyes', Rehabilitation='$Rehabilitation', Number='$Number', Psychological='$Psychological', diagnostic='$diagnostic', eyes='$eyes', burns='$burns', head='$head', symptoms='$symptoms', memory='$memory', scaring='$scaring', genitals='$genitals', dental='$dental', stomach='$stomach', directly='$directly', behalfclient='$behalfclient', investigations='$investigations', injuries='$injuries', duties='$duties', Wherepain='$Wherepain', pain='$pain', aggravates='$aggravates', eases='$eases', Movement='$Movement', neural='$neural', UnderstandNPRS='$UnderstandNPRS', NPRSassessment='$NPRSassessment', yourhobbies='$yourhobbies', hobbiesaffected='$hobbiesaffected', social='$social', activities='$activities', lifestyle='$lifestyle', avoiddriving='$avoiddriving', grip='$grip', flashbacks='$flashbacks', braking='$braking', past='$past', psychologically='$psychologically' WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);

// test by Fred start
 while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo '<a href="update.php?Reference='. $rows['Reference'].' ">update test</a>';
 }
// test by Fred end


if (!$_REQUEST['sceneaccident'] || !$_REQUEST['notrequiretreatment'] || !$_REQUEST['house'] || !$_REQUEST['recommendations'] || !$_REQUEST['Prognosis'] || !$_REQUEST['CV'] || !$_REQUEST['cervical'] || !$_REQUEST['heat'] || !$_REQUEST['ice'] || !$_REQUEST['lumbar'] || !$_REQUEST['medication'] || !$_REQUEST['posture'] || !$_REQUEST['sport'] || !$_REQUEST['given'] || !$_REQUEST['organs'] || !$_REQUEST['deformity'] || !$_REQUEST['otherchanges'] || !$_REQUEST['receivingtreatment'] || !$_REQUEST['surgery'] || !$_REQUEST['Impression'] || !$_REQUEST['management'] || !$_REQUEST['ifyes'] || !$_REQUEST['Rehabilitation'] || !$_REQUEST['Number'] || !$_REQUEST['Psychological'] || !$_REQUEST['diagnostic'] || !$_REQUEST['eyes'] || !$_REQUEST['burns'] || !$_REQUEST['head'] || !$_REQUEST['symptoms'] || !$_REQUEST['memory'] || !$_REQUEST['scaring'] || !$_REQUEST['genitals'] || !$_REQUEST['dental'] || !$_REQUEST['stomach'] || !$_REQUEST['directly'] || !$_REQUEST['behalfclient'] || !$_REQUEST['investigations'] || !$_REQUEST['injuries'] || !$_REQUEST['duties'] || !$_REQUEST['Wherepain'] || !$_REQUEST['pain'] || !$_REQUEST['aggravates'] || !$_REQUEST['eases'] || !$_REQUEST['Movement'] || !$_REQUEST['neural'] || !$_REQUEST['UnderstandNPRS'] || !$_REQUEST['NPRSassessment'] || !$_REQUEST['yourhobbies'] || !$_REQUEST['hobbiesaffected'] || !$_REQUEST['social'] || !$_REQUEST['activities'] || !$_REQUEST['lifestyle'] || !$_REQUEST['avoiddriving'] || !$_REQUEST['grip'] || !$_REQUEST['flashbacks'] || !$_REQUEST['braking'] || !$_REQUEST['past'] || !$_REQUEST['psychologically'] )

{
 echo ('You did not complete all of the required fields');
 echo "<BR>";
 echo '<a href="update.php?Reference='. $rows['Reference'].' ">update</a>'; 
 }
 else {
 echo "Successful";
 echo "<BR>";
 echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
 } 

 ?>
```

UPDATE 3

```
{
 echo ('You did not complete all of the required fields');
 echo "<BR>";
 while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo '<a href="update.php?Reference='. $rows['Reference'].' ">update</a>';
 }}
 else {
 echo "Successful";
 echo "<BR>";
 echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
 }
```

UPDATE 4

```
 {
 echo ('You did not complete all of the required fields');
 echo "<BR>";
 while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo '<a href="update.php?Reference= ">update</a>';
 }}
 else {
 echo "Successful";
 echo "<BR>";
 echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
 }
```

UPDATE 5

```
{
 echo ('You did not complete all of the required fields');
 echo "<BR>";
 while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo '<a href="update.php?Reference='. $rows['Reference'].' ">update</a>';
 }
 } // end of while loop
 else {
 echo "Successful";
 echo "<BR>";
 echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
 }
```

Update 6

```
<?php

require_once('auth.php');

 $host="xxx"; // Host name 
 $username="xxx"; // Mysql username 
 $password="xxx"; // Mysql password 
 $db_name="xxx"; // Database name 
 $tbl_name="xxx"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of Reference that sent from address bar
 $Reference=$_GET['Reference'];

// Retrieve data from database 
 $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
 ?>
```

Comment: Do a `print_r($rows);` to make sure it actually contains data.

Comment: do I just add that to the end of that row of code? cheers for your help

Comment: why are you using echo inside <? ?> tags if it is already inside. is should look like echo '<a href="update.php?Reference='. $rows['Reference'].' ">update</a>';

Comment: Probably just a typo, also do you have `short_open_tag` enabled in PHP.ini? If you don't then you need to use `<?PHP ?>` instead of the shorthand equivalent.

Comment: I don't think I have enabled that

Comment: i have tried this and it doesn't seem to be bringing through the reference field 
    echo '<a href="update.php?Reference='. $rows['Reference'].' ">update</a>';

Comment: @Abhipranay Chauhan - I have tried the line you wrote, it just looks like this part doesn't work, even though it probably should
    '. $rows['Reference'].' 
any ideas why?

Comment: can any one just point me in the right direction please?

Comment: @LukeNicholls i checked the line i gave it is echoing what you want.please do check if $rows['Reference'] is set and not blank as suggested by Ben Fortune.

Comment: where do i use print_r($rows); to get the data i need.

Comment: @LukeNicholls Did you try `<a href="update.php?Reference=<?php echo $rows['Reference']; ?>">update</a>` - also make sure your DB field/column is in fact called `Reference`

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have just tried that and doesn't work, i have copied the reference from other logic which works and i confirmed the field is called reference. cheers

Comment: @LukeNicholls `reference` and `Reference` are two different animals altogether. Also, assuming you have a record called `123456` and hardcoding it into your browser, what happens when you do `http://www.yourwebsite.com/localip/update.php?Reference=123456` does anything come up?

Comment: its Reference, when I actually enter the record 123456 life you said, it brings through the data as expected, everything seems correct just the part to bring through the Reference doesn't work. do you have any other ideas? cheers

Comment: @LukeNicholls I need to know your DB structure. Also it could be the way you are setting your actual PHP/MySQL code, this could be the factor at play here. Show your full PHP including what you have already posted.

Comment: i think your right as im pretty new to PHP and my sql. what do you need to know? is there a better way i can tell/show you? cheers

Comment: @LukeNicholls The "best" way, edit your question with your full code, leaving out actual SQL credentials and marked as `xxx` - that's what I suspect is happening, a bad SQL call.

Comment: i have amended the question hopefully that could help you. P.S.- there might be a few errors in there, im currently learning PHP myself

Comment: @LukeNicholls I found your problem. You're using `POST` when it needs to be a `GET` - change your form to be `method="get"` then change `$Reference=$_POST['Reference'];` to `$Reference=$_GET['Reference'];` to test and you'll see it's going to work. Better yet, change all your `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Thanks fred, i have changed them all to $_REQUEST now and have changed the form to "GET" now instead of "POST". can i just confirm this line is what i need to use.         echo '<a href="update.php?Reference='. $rows['Reference'].' ">update</a>'; as it still doesn't bring through the Reference

Comment: @LukeNicholls You're welcome. Are there any records in your `Reference` DB? This should be working.

Comment: yes there are records and if i type the Reference in manually it works, but at the minute its just blank after - echo '<a href="update.php?Reference=. i will edit my question again and add the updated code

Comment: @LukeNicholls Ok, what I now suspect is that you need to reference/loop `$rows` in a query. Since you're using `MySQL_` instead of `MySQLi_` makes it harder for me to help you; they're not the same syntax.

Comment: @LukeNicholls Try this `while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){` above `echo '<a href="update.php?Reference='. $rows['Reference'].' ">update</a>';` then close it with a brace `}`

Comment: is it easy to change from MySQL_ to MySQLi_?

Comment: @LukeNicholls I for one don't like doing it. For some of the functions, all you need to do is add an `i` while in other cases is a different method and they ALL have to reflect that change. Have you tried my above comment with the `while` loop?

Comment: i have put your comment in to the code and it look like it will work but it has an error on the line for 'else {'

Comment: @LukeNicholls It's because you need to add another closing brace `}` after `echo '<a href="update.php?Reference='. $rows['Reference'].' ">update</a>';` for the `while` loop.

Comment: yes you were right, i have added the closing bracket and it doesnt have any errors. cheers.  there is no "update" link now though?

Comment: @LukeNicholls Ok, get rid of the brace `}` you added and place it underneath `echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";` instead. Try that or another combination. But that should work now. I will then make it as an answer.

Comment: @LukeNicholls Everything good now?

Comment: @Fred-ii- -  sorry to be a real pain, but i have tried the brace in all places and doesnt seem to work. any idea? many thanks -see update 4

Comment: @LukeNicholls Brace at the wrong place. See the edit I made, UPDATE 5

Comment: (using Dreamweaver atm) when i copy update 5 it say there is an error on the "else" line again. and the page doesnt work.

Comment: @LukeNicholls I re-edited UPDATE 5 (reload the page). Your #4 had `echo '<a href="update.php?Reference= ">update</a>';` so I replaced it with `echo '<a href="update.php?Reference='. $rows['Reference'].' ">update</a>';` and I put the ending brace there instead. That has to work. If not, I don't know what else it could be.

Comment: @LukeNicholls I take it that it's still not working 100% then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if your still on the topic, its just the '>update</a>' link isn't on the webpage. if not many thanks for your help, you have helped alot

Comment: @LukeNicholls Am under the impression that the link will show if the field was not filled, try leaving it blank till the error message shows `You did not complete all of the required fields`

Comment: @LukeNicholls I added the `while` loop in your **EDIT 2** section. Look for `// test by Fred start` and `update test` link. See if that works.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for coming back to me i have added this exactly where you said and // the same statement where you originally put it and still the same issue

Comment: @Fred-ii- someone suggested this  echo "<a href='update.php?Reference={$rows['Reference']}'>update</a>\n"; but it displays the update link multiple times?

Comment: @LukeNicholls You will need to put that `echo` outside the `while` loop, that's why it's showing up multiple times.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  do you think that would work?

Comment: @LukeNicholls Probably, give it a try and see.

Comment: @LukeNicholls Quick question. How does the reference `123456` come into play? Is that a number that the "user" enters or that "you" enter? I'm a bit lost at this point as to how your code works.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have put an update (6) where the reference comes into play which is within form page, and just before that a link is pressed from a list of records which brings through the reference field.---- is there an easy way to pu the 4 space indents in the code on here so i can show you all the infomation on each page

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
echo "<a href='update.php?Reference='". $rows['Reference']."'>update</a>";
```

Comment: I have just traied this but still doesn't bring through the reference field, is it something I may have missed earlier in the page? cheers